# Drift velocity vs acceleration due to an electric field

Tags: electric-fields, electrons, material-science

So my understanding is that when you have electrons moving in a vacuum (like in an electron gun), applying an electric field across it will accelerate the electrons across the gap.
Electrons moving with a net velocity of approximately zero at one end of the electric field will be moving with a final velocity equal to what's shown in the picture after crossing the gap with that voltage across.
[image]
However, with drift velocity of a material (like a segment of wire, or graphene or other material), is the idea that with electrons drifting in a material that they will all effectively move with the same velocity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, with drift velocity of a material (like a segment of wire, or
> graphene or other material), is the idea that with electrons drifting
> in a material that they will all effectively move with the same
> velocity?

In contrast to electrons located in a vacuum and subjected to the force of an electric field where the electrons encounter no resistance and thus accelerate,  electrons moving in a material under the influence of an electric field alternatively gain KE from the field and lose KE in collisions with the particles of the material.

The overall result is the electrons collectively move with an average velocity called the drift velocity. The velocity of the individual electrons can vary above and below that average.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

A simple picture of electrons in a metal wire is this... Free electrons are accelerated by the electric field set up by the applied voltage. This adds velocity along the wire to their existing (very much greater) thermal velocity. The accelerated electrons  will collide with vibrating ions in the lattice (they would even without the electric field on account of their random thermal velocity). On colliding, electrons will on average lose their extra velocity due to the electric field, but will acquire it once more before losing it again and so on. The result is an average drift velocity along the wire, rather than a sustained acceleration.